# Variable (Pay) defined in If statement not printing

Tags: python

```
def totalPays(hours,rate):
    if hours <= 40:
        pay = hours * rate

    if hours > 40:
        payot = (40 * rate) + (hours - 40) * rate * 1.5

hours = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
rate = float(input("Enter hourly rate: "))

print(pay)
```

Can someone help, I have tried multiple things to try to fix it but I can't seem to figure it out (New to Python).
Line 11: NameError: name 'pay' is not defined.
Why is 'pay' not defined even though I defined it in the If statement.

Comment: pay is inside your function and not a global variable. Check for variable scope in python

Comment: just call the function and add return statement to both if blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def totalWages(hours,rate):
    if hours <= 40:
        pay = hours * rate

    if hours > 40:
        payot = (40 * rate) + (hours - 40) * rate * 1.5

hours = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
rate = float(input("Enter hourly rate: "))

print(pay)
```

Ok, you never called the function, therefor pay is never defined.
Intead call the function (which needs a return) and store it in a variable `pay`
**Fixed Code**

```
def totalWages(hours,rate):
    if hours <= 40:
        pay = hours * rate
        return pay
    if hours > 40:
        payot = (40 * rate) + (hours - 40) * rate * 1.5
        return payot
hours = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
rate = float(input("Enter hourly rate: "))
pay = totalWages(hours,rate)
print(pay)
```